# Packaging NDK, .so *and* other Java code in a single Android library

Tags: android, android-ndk, eclipse-adt

I use JNI to build a .so (via NDK), and I have some Java code that provides certain functionality, calling the JNI/native functions when appropriate.

I would like this encapsulate this in an Android library, such that other apps can just import the library, and use the Java classes (which will in turn access the native functions).

*Is this possible?*

> That is, can we encapsulate the .so/JNI *and other Java code* into a
>   single library, that other apps can reference?

So far I can only get it working by having each app import an Android library for the Java classes, and import/build the .so/JNI stuff separately. Looking to improve portability..